# npm run build command is failing after installing jsonwebtoken package in reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, jwt, zendesk

I want to use zendesk authentication using jwt token. When I am installing jsonwebtoken npm package, npm run build is failing in azure devops pipeline. But, npm start command is working locally. I am also using "uniqid": "5.1.0" package to generate a unique id.

node version is v8.9.0
npm version is 5.6.0
[image]

Comment: Can you please share full console output of your npm run build command?

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

*Clean cache and delete node_modules folder.*

Follow these steps:

- Clean cache (*npm cache clean --force*)
- Delete node_modules folder (*rm -rf node_modules*)
- Delete package-lock.json file (*rm -f package-lock.json*)
- Do fresh install (*npm install*)

Had fixed this issue myself couple of times.

Comment: It's bit difficult to reproduce this kind of issue. Can you share the code link? so that i can try. If you can't then try to reproduce the issue with sample project.